# Height of the list item should automatically increase with size of div inside it

Tags: html, css

I have the following mark up:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="stuff site-content lists">
      <li>
        <div class="nearby"> 20 </div>
        <h1> name</h1>
      </li>
</ul>
```

`css` is:

```
.nearby{width: 85px; 
   height: auto; 
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px; 
   font-size: 26px; 
   text-align: center; 
   padding: 15px 0; 
   border: 2px #c1c1c1 solid; 
   background: #fafafa; 
}
li{padding: .7em 15px;
   display: block;
}
```

Unfortunately, the div doesn't sit nicely in the middle as it is too tall. Anyway, the `li` item could also increase in height so that its padding is dependent on the `div` rather than the `h1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add the following for it to work:

```
li{overflow:hidden;}
```

When setting the parent of a floated element to `overflow:hidden;` you force it to wrap the entire floated content. This is a very useful technique and it is used alot.

Answer (score 0):

set `float:left`  for ul and li both i always have this problem try it